# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python

I am trying to use pop with list but it is giving me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

and the way i am using pop is:

```
vertex = my_queue.pop()
```

Whats confusing is that when i use print(vertex), it print outs the data which means that it is working perfectly but showing error at the same time is confusing.`

My Code:

```
 def bfs(my_data):
      my_queue = [] #array to store vertices
      #print(my_data[0])
      my_queue.insert(0, my_data[0]); 
      my_data[0]['visited'] = '1';
      int_vertex = []

      while my_queue:
                vertex = my_queue.pop()
                for n_vertex in vertex['neighbors']:
                          #print(type(n_vertex))
                          int_vertex = int(n_vertex)
                          if my_data[int_vertex]['visited'] == '0':
                                    my_data[int_vertex]['visited'] = '1'
                                    test.insert(0, my_data[int_vertex])
                                    my_queue = str(test)
```

Where my_queue & my_data are the list and vertex is dict

Comment: Do you have a string that just looks like a list? Something like `"[1, 2, 3]"`?

Comment: Not allowed to post the code. Let me edit my Question

Comment: it'd be better if you show us where you get/fill "my_queue"

Comment: Don't try to post code into a comment; edit your question.

Comment: Also, show the whole traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: Where does that `test` list come from? You're not creating it anywhere. Is it a global variable or something?

Answer (score 5):

Look at these two lines:

```
vertex = my_queue.pop()
# ...
my_queue = str(test)
```

So, after the first time through the loop, `my_queue` is obviously a `str`, because you explicitly convert it to one.

You can see a list of [String Methods](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) and [Common Sequence Operations](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common). Notice that `pop` doesn't appear anywhere there. That's because `pop` is only a method of [Mutable Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) like `list`. Which is exactly what this error is telling you:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

And even if there were such a method, what would you expect it to return? The first character of the string? How would that work with `for n_vertex in vertex['neighbors']`, which clearly expects `vertex` to be a `dict` (or other Mapping type), not a single-character string?

---

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do at the end, but I suspect that removing the `str()` call won't be enough on its own to solve all of your problems. You're appending to a list named `test` that isn't defined anywhere in the function, so presumably it's a global variable. You then throw away whatever was in `my_queue` and instead assign it to that global variable. That can't possibly be what you want. My guess—but this is only a guess—is that you want to replace those last two lines with this:

```
my_queue.insert(0, my_data[int_vertex])
```

Comment: I am actually trying to implement Breadth First Search in Python that pops out a vertex from my_queue and add its neighbors in my_queue and following recursive function it performs the same action with the neighbors.

Comment: @JeffCraine: Yes, I get from the names that you're doing a BFS on a graph, but without knowing what `temp` is supposed to be doing or where it comes from, I can't be sure that my last change actually fixes your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

pop method is not supported by string objects in python.
I believe my_queue is not referring to list object but it referring to string. 
via debug or using type(), isinstance() builtin you can come to know which data type my_queue is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) to check at which line your list type becomes a string.
When you get to the setrace, type for example the following to check the type:

```
type(my_queue)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Because pop is not a string function you have to make your own function

Comment: Could you please add a more complete answer.